# How to figure out the thread pool of thread [Kotlin]?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider the following piece of code:

```
suspend fun childTaskExecutor()  {
    GlobalScope.future(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
        logger.info("[childTaskExecutor] running on ${currentThread.name} group : ${currentThread.threadGroup}")
    }.awaitOrNull()
}
```

When I run this the output is:
`[childTaskExecutor] running on DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 group : java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]`

When I change the context to `Dispatchers.IO` the output is:
`running on DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 group : java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]`

I want to be able to figure out which thread pool does the thread belong to (IO, Default, Unconfined). Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A coroutine dispatcher is not quite the same as a thread pool. A coroutine dispatcher is backed by a thread pool, but each of them don't need to use a different thread pool. In fact, the threadpools of some of the built-in dispatchers actually overlap. That's why you see the same DefaultDispatcher-thread even when you use `Dispatchers.IO`.

This layout with overlapping thread pools make coroutines more efficient. The runtime doesn't necessarily have to switch threads when you switch from `Dispatchers.Default` to `Dispatchers.IO`.

If you want to see which coroutine dispatcher you are currently on, you can fetch it from the coroutine context. Like this:

```
// Prints the name of the coroutine dispatcher.
println(coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher])
```

Note that the companion object you access with `CoroutineDispatcher` is currently experimental API, so you need to opt in to use it.

Comment: just a little hint, the `.Key` is not required when accessing elements of a coroutineContext. e.g. you can write `coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher]`, or `coroutineContext[Job]`, if you want to access the current job

Comment: @AdrianK Ah, nice. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so the threadpools overlap.
But let's say I have setup a max limit for Dispatchers.Default as 64 and IO as 64.
I hope I am still getting a total of 128 threads.

Comment: @ShivangTripathi I think they will still share thread pools if you configure the max limit for them. I'm not really sure if you will get 128 total threads.